Characterizing the probability distribution of sums of randomly selected combinations
Consider a problem with $n$ agents, so that each agent $n_i$ is endowed with some nonzero share $s_i$ so that $\sum_{i\in I}s_i=1$. For example, with three agents, possible endowments are the solutions to $x+y+z=1,s.t.,x,y,z\in(0,1)$.
Given a specific endowment, I randomly draw a strict subset of cardinality $t$. Call this subset $T$.
The number of possible such subsets is $\binom nt$. Given a subset, I am interested in characterizing the distribution of $\sum_{i\in T}s_i$, i.e., the sum of the shares of the agents in the subset. The expectation of this sum is $\frac{t}{n}$, but can we say anything more about it? What would the variance of such a distribution look like? In the degenerate case of $s_i=s_j$ for all $i\neq j$, clearly $\sigma^2=0$, but what about in non-degenerate cases?

I assume your subset is drawn uniformly at random. You can certainly obtain the variance. Let $X_i$ be $s_i$ times the indicator function that agent $i$ is included in the subset. Then your sum is $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. You can use the formula for the variance of a sum based on the variances and pairwise covariances of the summands: $\text{Var}\big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\big)=\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i) + 2\sum_{1\leq i < j\leq n} \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j)$.
